# Get string between quotes using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that is basically an XML node, and I need to extract the values of the attributes.  I am trying to use the following C# code to accomplish this:

```
string line = "<log description="Reset Controls - MFB - SkipSegment = True" start="09/13/2011 10:29:58" end="09/13/2011 10:29:58" timeMS="0" serviceCalls="0">"
string pattern = "\"[\\w ]*\"";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(line, pattern))
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2));
}
```

The problem is that this is only returning the last occurrence from the string ("0" in the above example), when each string contains 5 occurrences.  How do I get every occurrence using C#?

Comment: Why don't you just parse the XML like it's XML?

Comment: Try with lazyness-modifier - "\"[\\w ]*?\"".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to parse XML with regular expressions. Use an XML API instead. It's simply a *really bad idea* to try to hack together "just enough of an XML parser" - you'll end up with incredibly fragile code.

Now your line isn't *actually* a valid XML element at the moment - but if you add a `</log>` it will be.

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(line + "</log>");
foreach (XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
}
```

That's *slightly* hacky, but it's better than trying to fake XML parsing yourself.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I agree that creating my own parser was a bad idea, but I was getting nowhere trying to use an XML API.  One minor adjustment, though; I had to add () to element.Attributes due to a "foreach cannot operate on a method group..." error.  Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you need to escape your string for double-quotes and add a semi-colon:

```
string line = "<log description=\"Reset Controls - MFB - SkipSegment = True\" start=\"09/13/2011 10:29:58\" end=\"09/13/2011 10:29:58\" timeMS=\"0\" serviceCalls=\"0\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer your question, your `pattern` should probably be `"\"[^\"]*\""`because `\w` won't match spaces,  symbols,  etc.